# Add point on the editor toolbar is not available to click on?

Tags: point, map-editor

I have created a new shapefile, I chose a coordinate system and enabled the editor. When I now start editing and choose the new shapefile I created, it is not available to me to click add a new point. The button is just grey. Have I done something wrong when creating the shapefile?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of what you see, i.e. the grey button, and add the software you are using also?

Comment: Ok, I have now managed to actually click on the add a point to edit sketch button, by selecting my shapefile in the create features part. However, once I have chosen the location for my points and I click to save the edit, the points disappear and are not visible nor they are added to the attribute table.

Comment: I just deleted the shapefile and created a new one, and now it seems to work. Thank you